# how to mysql_fetch_assoc for two select statement which is given in OR operator to select form either tables

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

How to `mysql_fetch_assoc` array for either of `select` statement if either one is selected and display them ?

```
$query1= "SELECT name, email_id,mobile_number from tablename where `user_id='$id'"` 
            OR      
        "SELECT guser_name, guser_email from tablename1 where user_id='$id'";

if($q=mysql_query($query1))
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
    $name = $row['guser_name'];
    $name1 = $row1['name'];
    $mail1 = $row1['email_id'];
    $mail= $row['guser_email'] ;
    $phone = $row1['mobile_number']
```

Comment: you can use `unionAll`

Comment: @DipeshParmar The queries have a different number of columns, so a Union All won't work without changes to the queries.

Comment: thanks but how to add $query1=  "SELECT guser_name, guser_email from googlelogin where user_id='$id'" UNION ALL " SELECT name, email_id,mobile_number from customer where user_id='$id'" ;   like this . i am new to these fluffeh

Comment: is der way to fetch result from both select statment and display it ?

Comment: @Gokul Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below. This way, all rows whether coming from table1 or table2 can be accessed using same key in array obtained from mysql_fetch_assoc.

```
select name1 as name,email1 as email, mobile1 as mobile FROM table1 WHERE id=1
UNION ALL 
select name2 as name,email2 as email, '' as mobile FROM table2 WHERE id=1
```

Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d81c/1